# Angular Equivalent of angularjs's module.requires.push("modName")

Tags: angular, typescript

My problem is that I need to load an angular module programatically at runtime.
It doesn't exactly have to be dynamic module loading though. All the modules can be loaded at the 1 first bootstrapping.

Basically, I am about to begin upgrading my application from angularJs to angular, and the application architecture is a main app, with configurable plugins.

The plugins are angularJs modules, so basically I have my main app module

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

Then based on configuration it will do

```
angular.module('app').requires.push('plugin1');
angular.module('app').requires.push('plugin2');
```

Plugin 1 and 2 js files will be added to the html, and loaded first, finally we do

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

Now we have the full application with its 2 plugins loaded but decoupled from the main app.

So... now I need to do the same thing in angular, but something so trivial in angulaJs seems really complicated in angular.

Is there a fast and easy way to do this?
Do I really need to look into dynamic module loading, or is there another decoupled, but not really dynamic approach that might work?

Thanks in advance!